# Websphere admin console does not come up if struts.jar 1.2.7 is present in lib/ext

Tags: windows, websphere

I am migrating an app to WAS 7.0 (fix pack 13). The app uses a number of jars which are located in the Appserver\lib\ext dir. If struts.jar (1.2.7) is present when invoking the WAS admin console it crashes with an error 404 screen (below). If I remove struts.jar from lib\ext the admin console works, naturally my app needs it. WAS jar loader is set to parent first, my app is parent last.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Error screens and dump, note the login screen appears normally, this is after clicking "Log in":

Error404

An error occurred while processing request:%2Fibm%2Fconsole%2Findex.do

Message:org.apache.struts.tiles.DefinitionsFactoryException: IO Error while parsing file '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.core/console-defs.xml'. Connection timed out: connect

Details:

javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.apache.struts.tiles.DefinitionsFactoryException: IO Error while parsing file '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.core/console-defs.xml'. Connection timed out: connect
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:534)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FilterProxyServlet.dispatch(FilterProxyServlet.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FilterProxyServlet.service(FilterProxyServlet.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:933)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:985)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:682)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)

Answer (score 8):

The WAS console uses it's own version of Struts.

Since you have placed a different version of struts (high up in the classloader - lib/ext), the WAS console has trouble.

It is in 99.99 % of the cases a bad idea to dump in jars like these to lib/ext.

You can use application specific classpath or use shared library approach if you need these jars to be shared across multiple applications.

Reconsider the usage of placing jars in lib/ext.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that was going to be the case. I have tried the shared library approach, but I found the jars were not actually in use after WAS started up, will revisit that topic and figure out what I might have overlooked/misconfigured.

Comment: It is fairly straight forward. Have a look at this for quick reference - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tcws_sharedlib_create.html

Comment: That looks like what I did ... will revisit and dig further... again, thanks.